# Testing for Rounding Errors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, biginteger, rounding-error

How can I determine if a number is too big (will cause rounding errors if math is performed) in JavaScript.

For example, I have a function that formats percentages. If it cannot format the passed in value correctly, I want it to return the value exactly as it was passed in.

```
function formatPercent(x, decimals) {
     var n = parseFloat(x);                 // Parse (string or number)
     if ($.isNumeric(n) === false) {
         return x;                          // Return original if not a number
     } else {
         return n.toFixed(decimals) + '%';  // Return formatted string
     }
 };

alert(formatPercent(276403573577891842, 2)); // returns 276403573577891840.00%
```

Since formatting such a huge number is a corner case and not expected, I'd prefer to just return the number as it was passed in. What is the limit before the rounding errors start and how would I check for them?

**Update:**

[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t) says precision works up to +/- 9007199254740992. I am testing to see if that is all I need to check against to safely fail and return the passed in value unmodified.

Comment: This depends on the source of the numbers, really, and what you intend to do with them. I don't honestly see an application involving percentages that large, so what is this really for?

Comment: I am writing unit tests (QUnit) and want to make sure my results are reliable. I have similar functions that format numbers (with commas, decimals) for things like impressions, and clicks that would be bigger numbers ... still not expecting a 64-bit int like the one above, but in writing my unit tests, it would be nice to catch it anyway.

Comment: The article you linked does make sense
(9007199254740992).toString(16) == "20000000000000"
So I guess just adding an if statement saying if it's above or equal to that value will determine whether or not to trust that's its real value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used to catch [too big or too small integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t):

```
function getSafeNumber(x) {
     var n = parseFloat(x);    // Parse and return a floating point number
     if ($.isNumeric(n) === false || 
         n >= 9007199254740992 || 
         n <= -9007199254740992) {
         return false;         // Not numeric or too big or too small
     } else {
         return n;             // return as number
     }
 };
```

Comment: Might want to do ``>=``... for example: ``(9007199254740993 > 9007199254740992) === false``

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If `n = 9007199254740993` it would return false as-is.

Comment: Put ``var n = 9007199254740993;n;`` into the console and see what it says. It will read ``9007199254740992``.

Answer (score 1):

If you always pass `x` in as a string, that will ensure that there are no rounding errors. The problem is that `276403573577891842` is being rounded right as the number literal is parsed, but if you use strings, that will never happen. Try doing this:

```
function formatPercent(x, decimals) {
    if(typeof x != "string" && typeof x != "number") return x;
    x = x+"";//convert to string if it is a number
    var r = /^(?:(\d+)(\.\d*)?|(\d*)(\.\d+))$/;// RegExp for matching numerical strings
    return x.replace(r, function(match, int, dec){
        if(decimals>0){
            int = (typeof int == "string"?int:"");//if passed string didn't have integers
            dec = (typeof dec == "string"?dec:".");//if passed string didn't have decimals
            while(dec.length-1<decimals) dec += "0";//pad zeroes until dec.length-1==decimals
            return int+dec.slice(0,decimals+1)+"%";//in case dec.length-1>decimals
        }
        int = (typeof int == "string"?int:"0");//if passed string didn't have integers
        return int+"%";
    });
    // Return formatted string or original string conversion if no match found
}

alert(formatPercent("276403573577891842", 1));// returns 276403573577891842.0%
alert(formatPercent("276403573577891842.55", 1));// returns 276403573577891842.5%
alert(formatPercent("276403573577891842.55", 0));// returns 276403573577891842%
alert(formatPercent(".55", 1));//returns .5%
alert(formatPercent(".55", 0));//returns 0%
alert(formatPercent(276403573577891842, 1));// returns 276403573577891840.0%
alert(formatPercent("this is not a number", 2));// returns this is not a number
alert(formatPercent({key:"not number or string"}, 2));// returns the object as it was
```

Even though formatPercent still fails in the case of passing a number, this will prevent rounding error from passed strings. Please note this is not incorrect, as the only case in which it will fail is when a number that is too large is hard-coded as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, +1 as this does solve the math problem. However, I don't think I'd want to use it in production as it's fairly complex and as you mentioned in your comment, handling numbers this great isn't needed. However, knowing when a value passed in is too big, is needed. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatPercent(x, decimals) {
     var n = parseFloat(x);                 // Parse (string or number)
     if ($.isNumeric(n) === false) {
         return x;                          // Return original if not a number
     } else {
         var d = Math.pow(10, decimals)
         return (Math.round(n * d) / d).toString() + "%";
      }
 };
```

Using rounding will drop the decimal if it's .00

Comment: This isn't correct, since running the code produces "276403573577891840%" rather than "276403573577891842%"

Comment: Ah true, max int is 2^53 per below. Works for smaller floats however. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t

Answer (score -1):

No greater than nine quardbillion will cause this type of error due to internal representation of no